# Freeing a PyTuple object

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

What is the proper way to free a `PyTuple` object using the Python C-API?

I know that tuples are somewhat special when it comes to the reference counting semantics, since `PyTuple_SetItem` "*steals*" the reference to the inserted element.  I also know that decrementing the reference of a tuple object decrements the reference count of all the elements in the tuple.

With this in mind, I would think it should be safe to say:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    PyObject* tup = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(tup, 0, PyLong_FromLong(100L));

    printf("Ref Count: %d\n", tup->ob_refcnt);
    Py_DECREF(tup);
}
```

But the last line causes a Segmentation Fault, when I decrement the tuple reference count.  I don't understand why this happens.  Right before the call to `Py_DECREF` the reference count is `1`, so what's the issue here?

Comment: The Py_DECREF will free the tuple but a Segmentation Fault at that point probably indicates that you have already corrupted memory in some earlier code. Look elsewhere in your code. If you can post a complete runnable sample that demonstrates the problem (probably not easy I know).

Comment: No, that is literally the entire program.  However, I added in the surrounding `#include` statements and `main` function if that helps.

Comment: First: Try adding `Py_Initialize();` at the beginning.

Comment: @Tomek, isn't that only necessary if you are going to embed the interpreter in your C-program?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Py_Initialize();`? Did it help? You need to call `Py_Initialize` before using any Python API call. Otherwise Python's internal variables won't be properly initialized; including those used for memory management.

Answer (score 3):

Add call to `Py_Initialize();` at the beginning of main and try again.

Comment: You're right, there's almost certainly some initialisation of either the tuple or long types that is being missed and hence failing on destruction.